# How to graph and find the x intercept of $h(x)=3\ln(x)-9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am working on a method to graph logarithm functions.  I know the log function is the inverse of the exponent function and I like to convert the log function into this form, $a^y=x$.  Then I start making tables to transform the parent function to $h(x)$.

How do I graph this function; $$h(x)=3\ln(x)-9$$  First I re-write the equation into a form I find more understandable.  The form is $$e^y=x$$  Then my first table is
$$ \begin{array}{c|lcr}
x & y \\
\hline \frac1e & -1 \\
1 & \phantom1 0 \\
e & \phantom1 1 \end{array}$$

The idea of these tables is to get the general shape of the graph by making these tables and then find the $x$ intercept.  To draw the general graph of $h(x)=3\ln(x)-9$ is to deal with the minus nine first.  I have tried to deal with the equation and graph of the equation in number of ways so far.  I don't know that this is the right idea.  I may want to multiply by $3$ first but I am not sure.  I just needed to get something down to start finding ways to graph these equations.  The picture is to show the graph.  The table then looks like this:
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x & y -9 \\
\hline \frac1e & -1-9=-10 \\
1 & 0-9= -9 \\
e & 1-9= -8 \\
\end{array}$$  [image: home work notebook]

I still am having a hard time finding how these graphs work when $y$ does not equal $-1, 0$, or $1$.  It makes it hard to find the $x$ intercept when that happens and to finish drawing the graph.

Comment: You can obtain $\ln x$ by typing `$\ln x$`.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $x$-intercept occurs when the curve touches the $x$-axis, i.e. when $y=0$. Therefore, finding the $x$-intercept is the same as finding the root of the function $h(x)=3\ln(x)-9$:
\begin{align}
3\ln(x) - 9 &= 0 \\[4pt]
\ln(x) &= 3
\end{align}
Can you do the rest?

Comment: You can obtain $\ln x$ by typing `$\ln x$`.

Comment: I can.  Thanks.  For some reason I thought x had to be solved first.

Comment: I see the x intercept is $(e^3, 0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $h(x)$ as $3 \ln x - 9 = 3(\ln x - 3)$. Then you can plot $\ln x - 3$ first, and then scale the $y$-axis by a factor of $3$.

As mentioned before, the $x$-intercept is when $\ln x = 3$:

[image]

Comment: What graphing software are you using.  I tried matplotlob for Python for a while but decided the math is what I wanted to learn and the software has to come after.

Comment: I'm using Desmos, but Geogebra also works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I just need to stretch it by 3.